# Matlab: Evaluating 2-argument function into a matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop

I have a user-input function that I need to plot in Matlab. This function is passed as a handle.

For a single-argument function, I can easily avoid for cycles—I just create an array of values and apply the function to it.

With a double-argument function (i.e. func(a, b)), I can't figure out how to avoid a for cycle.

What's the most effective way to get a range of values of a function taking two variables as arguments?

Comment: Are you talking about passing an array to the function?

Comment: Look for `meshgrid` (or `ndgrid` for more than 2 arguments).

Comment: Please explain more details

Comment: Please provide a code snippet

Comment: Depending on the operation it may be possible to vectorize, or even to exploit implicit singleton expansion. You need to tell what the function should actually do

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm plotting a function that the user inputs, so it can really be ANY kind of 2-argument function. The input range into that function are also set by the user.

Comment: In that case vectorization may not be possible. If the function doesn't automatically work element-wise you probably need the double `for` loop, or `arrayfun`,  which is more or less the same as a `for` loop